# Unexpected results with WHILE Loop - PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm retrieving unexpected results from the following WHILE loops and SQL SELECT statements:

```
<?php

    $sql="SELECT name, brand_id FROM brand WHERE (name IS NOT NULL OR name != '')
          AND (name != 'Hot Brands') ORDER BY name ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($brand=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<?
    $bid = $brand['brand_id'];

    /*
    *   Overall array by counting total pairs
    */

    $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM shop_orders WHERE
             DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
             BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
             AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'";

    $result_1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
    $total = mysql_fetch_array($result_1);

    /*
    *   Overall array counting total pairs by shop location 
    */

    $sql1 = "SELECT shop_order_location, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
              FROM shop_orders WHERE
              DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
              BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
              AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' GROUP BY shop_order_location";

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    while ($overall = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        ${$overall['shop_order_location'] == 'Bawtry' ? 'totalBawtry' :     $overall['shop_order_location']} = $overall['TOTAL'];
        ${$overall['shop_order_location'] == 'Chain' ? 'totalChain' : $overall['shop_order_location']} = $overall['TOTAL'];
        ${$overall['shop_order_location'] == 'Grantham' ? 'totalGrantham' : $overall['shop_order_location']} = $overall['TOTAL'];
        ${$overall['shop_order_location'] == 'Internet' ? 'totalInternet' : $overall['shop_order_location']} = $overall['TOTAL'];
    }

    /*
     *  Mens array - counting pairs of brand 
    */

    $sql2 = " SELECT shop_order_location, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM shop_orders
        LEFT JOIN product ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id = product.product_id
        WHERE DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
        AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' AND category = 'Mens' GROUP BY shop_order_location";

    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    while ($mens = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        ${$mens['shop_order_location'] == 'Bawtry' ? 'bawtryMens' : $mens['shop_order_location']} = $mens['TOTAL'];
        ${$mens['shop_order_location'] == 'Chain' ? 'chainMens' : $mens['shop_order_location']} = $mens['TOTAL'];
        ${$mens['shop_order_location'] == 'Grantham' ? 'granthamMens' : $mens['shop_order_location']} = $mens['TOTAL'];
        ${$mens['shop_order_location'] == 'Internet' ? 'internetMens' : $mens['shop_order_location']} = $mens['TOTAL'];
    }
    /*
    *   Ladies array - counting pairs of brand
    */  

    $sql3 = " SELECT shop_order_location, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM shop_orders
        LEFT JOIN product ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id = product.product_id
        WHERE DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
        AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' AND category = 'Ladies' GROUP BY shop_order_location";

    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    while ($ladies = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
        ${$ladies['shop_order_location'] == 'Bawtry' ? 'bawtryLadies' : $ladies['shop_order_location']} = $ladies['TOTAL'];
        ${$ladies['shop_order_location'] == 'Chain' ? 'chainLadies' : $ladies['shop_order_location']} = $ladies['TOTAL'];
        ${$ladies['shop_order_location'] == 'Grantham' ? 'granthamLadies' : $ladies['shop_order_location']} = $ladies['TOTAL'];
        ${$ladies['shop_order_location'] == 'Internet' ? 'internetLadies' : $ladies['shop_order_location']} = $ladies['TOTAL'];
    }

    /*
    *   SUM query - sales total cost
    */

    $sql4 = "SELECT SUM(shop_order_price) FROM shop_orders WHERE  
              DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
              BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'";

    $result4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
    ?>

    <?
        $showtotal = $row['SUM(shop_order_price)'] ;
        $showaverage = $row['SUM(shop_order_price)'] / $total['cnt'] ;
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong><?=$brand['name'];?></strong></td>
        <!-- Bawtry Mens figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($bawtryMens)) {echo '0';} if (isset($bawtryMens)) {echo $bawtryMens;}?></td>
        <!-- Bawtry Ladies figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($bawtryLadies)) {echo '0';} if (isset($bawtryLadies)) {echo $bawtryLadies;}?></td>
        <!-- Overall Bawtry Figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($totalBawtry)) {echo '0';} if (isset($totalBawtry)) {echo $totalBawtry;}?></td>
        <!-- Chains mens figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($chainMens)) {echo '0';} if (isset($chainMens)) {echo $chainMens;}?></td>
        <!-- Chain ladies figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($chainLadies)) {echo '0';} if (isset($chainLadies)) {echo $chainLadies;}?></td>
        <!-- Chain overall figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($totalChain)) {echo '0';} if (isset($totalChain)) {echo $totalChain;}?></td>
        <!-- Granthams mens figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($granthamMens)) {echo '0';} if (isset($granthamMens)) {echo $granthamMens;}?></td>
        <!-- Grantham ladies figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($granthamLadies)) {echo '0';} if (isset($granthamLadies)) {echo $granthamLadies;}?></td>
        <!-- Grantham overall figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($totalGrantham)) {echo '0';} if (isset($totalGrantham)) {echo $totalGrantham;}?></td>
        <!-- Internet mens figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($internetMens)) {echo '0';} if (isset($internetMens)) {echo $internetMens;}?></td>
        <!-- Internet ladies figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($internetLadies)) {echo '0';} if (isset($internetLadies)) {echo $internetLadies;}?></td>
        <!-- Internet overall figure -->
        <td align="center"><? if (empty($totalInternet)) {echo '0';} if (isset($totalInternet)) {echo $totalInternet;}?></td>
        <!-- Total pairs -->
        <td align="center"><?=$total['cnt']?></td>
        <!-- Total value -->
        <td align="center"><strong><?=round($showtotal, 2)?></strong></td>
        <!-- Total average -->
        <td align="center"><strong><?=round($showaverage, 2)?></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
<? } ?>
```

So the table currently appears as follows:

[image]

As you can see from the image above, it seems to copy the same results for the first 5 rows without the Total and then prints out random figures further down the table.

Could anybody tell me why it isn't going along each row and printing out the figures for each brand and returning to the top of the WHILE loop?

Comment: it seems like you have a lot of <? in your code instead of <?php, is it just a typo when you post the question?

Comment: @Andy - no not a typo. Does it really make a difference?

Comment: not really, my bad, didnt know there is a short tag. lol

Comment: That seems to be a problem with the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: @aduch - Could you please elaborate ...?

Comment: @Aphex22 I'm not quite sure in fact, I was just investigating and from  my experience I remembered I had duplicate column values problems with joining tables and grouping them by without specifying each of the values I wanted to select

Comment: @aduch - how did you solve the error in the end?

Comment: @Aphex22 sorry I thought I was clear. I had to specify each of the values that were in `SELECT` also in `GROUP BY` so that it looks like `SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM t0 JOIN t1 ON t0.id = t1.id GROUP BY c1,c2,c3` but in your case it should work correctly with `COUNT(*)` as it is an aggregate function on a single column, the only other option I can think of is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT shop_order_price)` but I may be wrong.

Comment: @aduch - Ok I'll try that and see how I get on. Thanks